# Will Lucene fuzzy search supports all languages

Tags: java, lucene, fuzzy

Will **Lucene fuzzy search** supports Chinese and Japanese languages? Can we use it for  all the languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lucene** fuzzy search works without connection to the language of the symbols, it's based on the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), or [Edit Distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). So, you shouldn't have any problems in applying it.